# DDD - Entity DTO representation on Repositories

Tags: domain-driven-design, dto, ddd-repositories

There are some properties that makes no sense for the domain but are essential for the repository, one example being the partition key.

Is it ok to have a DTO on my repository that will extend the base implementation of the entity, adding the relevant fields?

Comment: You have this problem because you don't separate the write from the read model; in `CQRS` you won't have this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is totally ok. As long as this DTO stays in the repository.
In Fowler's PoEAA:

> the Repository pattern is described as: Mediates between the domain
>   and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for
>   accessing domain objects.

As long as the repository is doing his job correctly (storing and fetching domain models) the implementation doesn't matter.
Just make sure that whatever implementation details of the repository doesn't get propagated in the rest of the project. If you add a DTO to your entity inside of the repository make sure you return the entity without the DTO or other irrelevant extra fields.

Comment: Careful: "repository", as described in the quoted text, is not in alignment with "repository" as described by Evans in chapter six of Domain Driven Design.  Evans uses repository between the application and the domain, not between the domain and the persistent store.

Comment: I think Evans is talking about the same repository pattern. Can you explain what does "between the application and the domain" means?